# Unable to locate package nvidia-355 and Hearthstone issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, wine

I have been trying to install Hearthstone via Wine, i have it configured properly, and have installed it before, but now for some reason i cant install the latest NVIDIA driver (which is 355) and in my proprietary drivers i get 340.

When i execute `sudo apt-cache search nvidia | grep -oE "nvidia-[0-9]{1,3}"`, i just get 346 for the newest version. And when i try to install it with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352`it says this:`Unable to locate package nvidia-352`.

And for Hearthstone this is what i get: [image]

All of these thing worked perfectly in 14.04, but i had to install NVIDIA Cuda for Wine and NVIDIA not to collide.

I use NVIDIA Geforce 740m and Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center, it says here it is 1.4.

Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you already have installed NVIDIA drivers, first uninstall every NVIDIA related software.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the latest stable NVIDIA (long-lived branch) drivers from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

When you want to have the latest (short-lived branch) drivers 355 - simply replace 352 with 355.

Comment: Don't forget to install nvidia-modprobe after reboot and then reboot another time or else CUDA won't work as it won't see nvidia drivers.